# I am trying to perform a query in SQL but I am not getting the correct value returned

Tags: sql, postgresql

The database is PostgreSQL 9.6.

```
create table candidates (
  id            int             not null,
  name          varchar,
  email         varchar,
  created_at    timestamptz,
  updated_at    timestamptz
);

insert into candidates values
  (1,   'John Snow',        'john@snow',    now()+interval '1 seconds', now()+interval '1 seconds'),
  (2,   'Bob Ross',         'bob@ross',     now()+interval '2 seconds', now()+interval '2 seconds'),
  (3,   'Kim Possible',     'kim@possible', now()+interval '3 seconds', now()+interval '3 seconds'),
  (4,   'Ash Ketchum',      'ash@ketchum',  now()+interval '4 seconds', now()+interval '4 seconds'),
  (5,   'Goku Son',         'goku@son',     now()+interval '5 seconds', now()+interval '5 seconds'),
  (6,   'Mortimer Smith',   'morty@smh',    now()+interval '6 seconds', now()+interval '6 seconds');

create table jobs (
  id            int             not null,
  title         varchar,
  positions     int,
  created_at    timestamptz,
  updated_at    timestamptz
);

insert into jobs values
  (1,   'Night Watch Commander',    1,      now()+interval '11 seconds',    now()+interval '11 seconds'),
  (2,   'Pokemon Master',           8,      now()+interval '12 seconds',    now()+interval '12 seconds'),
  (3,   'Blessed Painter',          100,    now()+interval '13 seconds',    now()+interval '13 seconds');

create table applications (
  id            int             not null,
  candidate_id  int             not null,
  job_id        int             not null,
  score         decimal,
  created_at    timestamptz,
  updated_at    timestamptz
);

insert into applications values
  (1,   1,  1,  90,     now()+interval '21 seconds',    now()+interval '21 seconds'),
  (2,   1,  3,  80,     now()+interval '22 seconds',    now()+interval '22 seconds'),
  (3,   2,  1,  10,     now()+interval '23 seconds',    now()+interval '23 seconds'),
  (4,   2,  2,  10,     now()+interval '24 seconds',    now()+interval '24 seconds'),
  (5,   2,  3,  99,     now()+interval '25 seconds',    now()+interval '25 seconds'),
  (6,   3,  1,  60,     now()+interval '26 seconds',    now()+interval '26 seconds'),
  (7,   3,  2,  70,     now()+interval '27 seconds',    now()+interval '27 seconds'),
  (8,   3,  3,  50,     now()+interval '28 seconds',    now()+interval '28 seconds'),
  (9,   4,  2,  90,     now()+interval '29 seconds',    now()+interval '29 seconds'),
  (10,  5,  1,  9000,   now()+interval '30 seconds',    now()+interval '30 seconds');
```

The query required names, title of job of their maximum application score and the score for that application for each candidate that has at least one application. (if there's a tie, pick the application that was created last). For the test use the website http://sqlfiddle.com

```
Expected output:
name             title                   score
Ash Ketchum      Pokemon Master          90
Bob Ross         Blessed Painter         99
Goku Son         Night Watch Commander   9000
John Snow        Night Watch Commander   90
Kim Possible     Pokemon Master          70
```

Comment: Tag properly!!!

Comment: Tag your dbms correctly. Is this postgres? You should also add the primary and foreign key constraints - no one should need to guess or assume how they are defined based on names only.

Comment: These are typically handled with `row_number()` or `rank()`. You order by score and pick only rows coming first. How do you want to handle ties?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and translate the title to English. Stack Overflow is English only.

Comment: Your edits are very much in the right direction.  Adding consumable sample data and expected results is great.  I would say your title is too vague for your problem, and you haven't shown what you've tried to this point.  But your edits were enough for me to give an answer (below).

Answer (score 0):

First rank by score in descending order partitioned by candidate.  This is what I do below in "rankApps".  Then select the top ranked for each candidate, join to candidates and jobs, and output.

```
with 

    rankApps as (

        select     candidate_id, job_id, score,
                   row_number() over(partition by candidate_id order by score desc) as rnk
        from       applications

    )

    select        c.name, j.title, a.score
    from          rankApps a
    join          candidates c on a.candidate_id = c.id 
    join          jobs j on a.job_id = j.id
    where         rnk = 1
    order by      c.name
```